# How to create and save multiple instances of an entity in core data for swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, class, core-data

When a user taps a create button in my app (iPhone) I am trying to create an instance of an entity and save it to core data. This means that the instance of the entity would be saved, then I could create a new instance of the same entity and save that. Both of these would be retrievable via NSFetchRequest.

From my best understanding, what usually happens is that there is only one instance of an entity available and its properties can be changed but the entity is not replicated. Any ideas, code samples, links to tutorials or sample projects would be great. Please remember that this is in swift 2.0

Comment: You can create as many objects of an entity as you want. *Any* CD tutorial should cover that. Or simply create a default "Master-Detail Application + Core Data" in Xcode and you'll see it yourself.

Comment: Think of the entity like an object. You can have multiple objects of the same type.

Comment: *"From my best understanding, what usually happens is that there is only one instance of an entity..."* This is completely incorrect. You would do well to [read up a little on how Core Data works](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)